# Building python for boost on ubuntu

Tags: python, boost

I have installed boost 1.57 and python 2.7.3 on ubuntu. I am trying to build /python/example/quickstart folder . when I try to give command

```
bjam toolset=gcc

build system bootstrapped
don't know how to make toolset=gcc
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...
```

In my home directory i have the user-config

```
using gcc
   : 4.6
   : /usr/bin/gcc ;
using python
   : 2.7
   : /usr ;
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 1):

Try running this first:

```
apt-get build-dep libboost-all-dev
```

E.g.: you might not have `build-essential` installed

---

#### Edit

Your Python location of `/usr` is incorrect. Also `/usr/bin/gcc` should likely be `/usr/bin/g++`.